# More selector condition (AND operator)

Tags: html, css, sass

I made few lines project to explain my problem.
Is there a way in `.scss` file, how to make condition like: "(1)FIRST type/child that (2)DOESN'T CONTAIN some class"?
I tried pile of variants, like this:

```
// SCSS:
&:first-of-type:not(.banned) {
   background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

OR:

```
// CSS:
circle::first-of-type:not(.banned) {
     background-color: yellowgreen;
  }
```

But nothing worked for me.

Here is the whole code of my super-tiny project where I am simulating this problem:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  
  &:first-of-type:not(.banned) {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
  }
}

.banned {
  background-color: brown;
}

// .circle::first-of-type:not(.banned) {
//   background-color: yellowgreen;
// }
```

```html
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle'></div> // <= this one I want to collor yellowgreen, but mainly in correct way I have described.
<div class='circle'></div>
<div class='circle'></div>
```

My codepen (Sass syntax works here): https://codepen.io/radekjakgit/pen/jOZgYGg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `first-of-type` for that as it will always return the first of that type of element among it's siblings - in your case always the first circle

If your banned always comes before the not banned circles, then you can use an adjacent sibling selector:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  
  &:first-of-type:not(.banned) {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
  }
}

.banned {
  background-color: brown;
}

.banned + .circle:not(.banned) {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle'></div> 
<div class='circle'></div>
<div class='circle'></div>
```

If you have a mixture of banned and not banned and you only want the first not banned after a banned, then you would need to use a combination of selectors:

```css
body {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  
  &:first-of-type:not(.banned) {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
  }
}

.banned {
  background-color: brown;
}

.banned + .circle:not(.banned) {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}


.banned + .circle:not(.banned) ~ 
.banned + .circle:not(.banned) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle'></div> 
<div class='circle'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle banned'></div>
<div class='circle'></div> 
<div class='circle'></div>
<div class='circle'></div>
```